# Can't delete a category in Wordpress

Tags: categories

I can't delete the Gallon Tanks category from my site, and I have no idea why. [My site](https://muchfish.com) isn't using the Gallon Tanks category at all in the navmenu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Start off by selecting Posts from the Dashboard and select Categories. After that, you will be redirected to a new page with options to edit the categories. Choose the category you want to remove and select the Delete option from the menu under the Category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the categories is always set as the default category, which will be used for an article, if no other category is selected when the post is created. In your case it looks like Gallon tanks is the default one.

You can change the default category from Dashboard > Settings > Writing > Default Post Category. After you've changed the default category, you should be able to delete the unneeded category.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-writing-screen/#writing-settings